# I need to authenticate to Splunk ONLY with apache2

Tags: ldap, apache2, splunk

Good afternoon everyone and first of all thank you very much for giving me a few minutes.
It turns out that we are using Splunk Free in a laboratory, which does not allow any type of authentication, which, even though it is a laboratory is not something that we approve and we are calm about it, I decided to implement Apache2 authentication for Splunk ...
First I want to perform the tests in a simple way, but then I would like to perform the authentication with LDAP, but for now I am stuck simply with the way to configure this, I would very much like if you could help me, I have done different tests but nothing, even trying to modify in ports.conf so that it listens for the port that the connection to Splunk is made, for the 8000 but of course, being assigned to Splunk it does not allow me to restart the service.
Greetings and thanks in advance to all.!

Comment: How exactly are you trying to authenticate when Splunk does not support authentication?  Please elaborate on "I have done different tests".

Comment: @RichG Very good days.

Well, I try to authenticate in the way I mentioned, I know that the Splunk Free version does not have any authentication method, so I am looking for a way to authenticate external to Splunk, but before accessing Splunk, I mean, with Apache2 I would like to perform a authentication before getting to Splunk, and I'm not sure how to do it.

Because, knowing that Splunk does not support authentication, I want Aapache2 to be before the Splunk website to authenticate me, and after doing so it redirects me to the Splunk website

Comment: I can't help with non-Splunk solutions.  Perhaps your network team can offer a solution.